# Can Mastadge herds be found in the Pegasus Galaxy?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

In the pilot for "[**Stargate: Atlantis**](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate:_Atlantis)", the Wraith Queen's dinner table has what appears to be the head of a [Mastadge](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Mastadge) for a centerpiece. The creature appeared in the 1994 movie "[Stargate](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_(movie))" (it was the large beast that took a liking to Daniel), but didn't otherwise appear in the series. However, the creature was seen on Abydos, which is located in the Milky Way galaxy... a galaxy that the Wraith have no knowledge of at this point.

[image]

This is probably just a tip of the hat to the film that started it all, but it also makes me wonder what the Wraith Queen is doing with an animal that's indigenous to a world they can't reach.

**Is the Mastadge head merely a nod to the original movie, or can this animal also be found in the Pegasus galaxy?**

Comment: Is it confirmed that it is a mastadge head? I'd say it's just a prop being reused, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @Sava - well, that could be the answer to the question. I'm trying to figure out if it's meaningful, merely an easter egg, or just a reused prop.

Comment: That is a great catch. I never noticed that easter egg before... Great question! I don't ever remember seeing any in Pegasus so I do think it is just an Easter Egg for true fans such as yourself that noticed it!